# Oxtoby - Thm 6.2 - There exists a strategy in which (A) wins iff $I_1 \cap B$ of first category

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category, lebesgue-measure

I am reading the book Measure and Category of Oxtoby. In Theorem 6.2 it is stated that

> There exists a strategy in which (A) wins iff $I_1 \cap B$ of first category

As in the picture below. **My question is:** Who is $I_1$ and how do we pick it.

[image: Oxtoby - 6.2]

Thank you,
Shir

Comment: Theorem 6.2 has an existential quantifier on $I_1$ - Don't drop the quantifier. You can also read the theorem as follows: In the Banach Mazur game with payoff set A, player (A) has a winning strategy iff A is comeager in some interval.

Comment: It is generally favorable to include the definition of the game being played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC the game in question is this: there is a set $B \subseteq I_0$, where $I_0$ is a closed interval (all intervals here are required to have positive length).  The first player $(A)$ chooses a closed interval $I_1 \subseteq I_0$, 
and then they alternate forever, choosing a closed subinterval $I_{k+1}$ of the previous interval $I_k$.
Player (A) wins if the intersection $\bigcap_k I_k$ is disjoint from $B$, otherwise player (B) wins.

In answer to your question: $I_1$ is a closed subinterval of $I_0$ such that $I_1 \cap B$ is a set of first category.  How we find it will depend on how $B$ is defined.   If $B$ has the property of Baire, it differs from some open set $U$ by a set of first category.  Then $I_1$ exists if and only if $U$ is not dense in $I_0$; if so, $I_1$ can be a small interval around any point not in the closure of $U$.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you!